# Make background of custom button not clickable

Tags: java, android, xml, button

Basically, I have a total of 6 ImageButtons. However, is it possible to have a layout like this?

Button Layout

[image: Button Layout]

One of my concerns is that the buttons will overlap each other.

Overlapping Buttons
[image: Overlapping Buttons]

How can I specify that the area with the image is the only clickable part? How will I make the transparent area not clickable?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/780

Comment: https://github.com/BCsl/CursorWheelLayout

Comment: https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create rotation wheel in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847225/create-rotation-wheel-in-android)

Comment: @NileshRathod This will do. However, the layout that I have doesn't really act like a wheel with the animation. Though, layout wise, this will do.

Comment: Trickily check the bitmap pixel in `onTouch`, refer to [prevent onClick method on transparent ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343266/how-to-prevent-onclick-method-on-transparent-portion-of-a-png-loaded-imageview). But It looks too heavy because create bitmap every touch.

Comment: The thread here shows how to create buttons of different shapes. You could adapt this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button